# Как можно остановить выход пользователя из KDE и запустить при этом GUI приложение?

Tags: linux, kde, altlinux, logout

Я хочу при выходе или logout пользователя в KDE запустить некое приложение для установки обновлений.
Alt linux KDE

Много чего перепробовал. Первое что пробовал это опция в настройках KDE. Там где можно добавить скрипт в автозапуск, так же можно и скрипт при выходе. Он отрабатывает но GUI не работает. Видимо запускается где то там на фоне. Потом пробовал поставить блокировки через systemd inhibit. Толку ноль. Они игнорирующийся. Единственно что пока получилось это создать программку с окном которое нельзя закрыть. Тогда при попытке выйти или вообще выключить компьютер мы получаем "Приложение не дает завершить работу" но держать это окно постоянно во время работы это бред. Должен же быть более красивый способ это все обработать. Например, словить сигнал от DBUS по типу PrepareForShutdown и отправить в ответ что то типа false.

Comment: Нужен ли сеанс пользователя для установки обновлений? Можно ли запустить это дело через unattended-upgrades?

Comment: Да, сенас юзера должен остаться, в этом и сложность. Надо это выполнить как то до завершения графической оболочки. Есть еще /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf и там session-cleanup-script, но оно выполняться уже после завершения оболочки. И опять же не подходит.

Answer (score 1):

Стандартный метод предотвратить завершение сессии в современном линукс десктопе это интерфейс dbus org.freedesktop.portal.Inhibit

Методом Inhibit создается dbus хандл с интерфейсом org.freedesktop.portal.Request и сигналом Response.

Сигнал выдаст что там пользователь ответил на запрос "Приложение препятствует ...". если Ок, то можно безопасно что-то запустить.

*Из староверских способов:*

На приложении наверное должен висеть обработчик сигнала системного SIGINT. Но так как родитель приложения менеджер сессии, а не дисплейный сервер, то скорее всего не прокатит.

Comment: Возился с Inhibit два дня почти, он ставиться, в списке systemd-ingibit --list его видно все ок. Жму завершить работу. И она завершается. Есть там Inhibit нету, без разницы. poweroff должна писать ошибку что мол есть Inhibit. Но она то же сразу завершает. Ставить пробовал через systemd-ingibit из скрипта в питоне. Это вообще работает в KDE?

Comment: xdg-portals что-то там кстановлен?

Comment: попробую вечерком